# The authenticated user has not granted the app xxx write access to the child file xxx, which would be affected by the operation on the parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I hit the below error when trying to insert the permission

"code": 403,
 "message": "The authenticated user has not granted the app xxx write access to the child file xxx, which would be affected by the operation on the parent"

Here is what I am doing

We have two Google Account,
1. API Account - we used to create folder and change the ownership to Business account 
2. Business Account - upload a file

now we try to share to folder to customer and we hit the above error

And here I using OAuth 2.0 Installed Applications to get the access token.

Please advise what is wrong I am doing here

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but I realize that its because of the scope for credential wasn't setup properly.  I only had DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA set which was not enough for downloading files.  Once I added DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE, and DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, I was able to download the file without any problem. Hope this helps.
P.S. if you are changing credentials, you have to delete the previously saved credential file.

Comment: I added SCOPES = ['https: //www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] to get mine working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the  [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_has_not_granted_the_app_appid_verb_access_to_the_file_fileid) you received '*403: The user has not granted the app*' because the request is not on the ACL for the file. The user never explicitly opened the file with this Drive app.

It is highly recommended to use  [Google Open Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker) and prompt the user to open the file or direct the user to Drive to open the file with the app.

Comment: How we can do this with API call and there might be more than one file will uploaded so do I have to open every file or is there any work around. Here some background what we are trying to do 

1. We create a Folder using a  API Account and share this folder to Lab Account and change ownership to Lab Account.
2. Lab Account users login to web browser and upload file.
3. Using API Account to share this whole Folder to Customer and here we got the issue.