# Python download file from Google Drive 403 permission

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, google-drive-api, mp4

In order to download a .mp4 file from my Drive, started using Google Drive API with target CLI tool which required to create new credentials.

Then, when downloading a file belonging to a user that only sent me the link using Google Drive API,

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API to download the file
    file_id = '1ZVFrwYaLClNrIk6TkshJZamHSS-59LLR'
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    filename = "test.mp4"
    #fh = io.BytesIO()
    fh = io.FileIO(filename, 'wb') # From - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309675/5675325
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\tiago\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 749, in next_chunk
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1ZVFrwYaLClNrIk6TkshJZamHSS-59LLR?alt=media returned "The user has not granted the app 682654872192 read access to the file 1ZVFrwYaLClNrIk6TkshJZamHSS-59LLR.">
```

This isn't someting new (even though it [might be a misleading error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649044/5675325)) and is [described in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors) as

> Resolve a 403 error: The user has not granted the app {appId} {verb}
>   access to the file {fileId}

which states that

> An appNotAuthorizedToFile error occurs when your app is not on the ACL
>   for the file.
>
> ...
>
> To fix this error, perform one of the following operations:
>
> - [Open the Google Drive picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#using_the_file_picker) and prompt the user to open the file.
> - Instruct the user to use your app to open the file using the [Open with](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-apps#open) context menu in the Drive UI.
>
> You can also check the isAppAuthorized field on a file to see if the
>   file was created by or opened with your app.

How to go over this and download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve it, I've just gone through the following two steps.

1. Change scope to `drive` - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53378988/5675325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611034/5675325).

   ```
   SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
   ```
2. Delete token.pickle and run the script again - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249610/5675325).

Then, manage to download the file and it works fine.

[image: File downloaded from Google Drive]

[image: .mp4 downloaded from Drive]